Keep getting an error that states "Error while evaluating property 'ifKaptClasspathIsPresent' of task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'."
In Android Studio, I keep getting an error that says "Error while evaluating property 'ifKaptClasspathIsPresent' of task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'." when trying to inject dependencies with Hilt.
There are no errors shown until I launch the app.
I'll show you the project
Here is the build.gradle.kts(Project)
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false
}

Here is the build.gradle.kts(App)
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
    kotlin("kapt")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.hilttest1"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.hilttest1"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_18
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_18
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "18"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.9.0")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")

    implementation ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.49")
    kapt ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44.2")
    kapt ("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.44.2")
    kapt ("com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.41")
    kapt ("com.google.androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.2.0")

    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
}
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
kapt {
    generateStubs = true

Here is the Application Class
import android.app.Application
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp

@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApplication : Application(){

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
    }
}`

Here is the Main Activity which also contains the user interface and injection classes
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import com.example.hilttest1.ui.theme.HiltTest1Theme
import javax.inject.Inject

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var someClass: SomeClass
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            HiltTest1Theme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Column {
                        Text(text = someClass.doAThing())
                        Text(text = someClass.doSomeOtherThing())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
class SomeClass
@Inject
constructor(
    val someOtherClass: SomeOtherClass
){
    fun doAThing(): String{
        return "Look I did a thing!"
    }

    fun doSomeOtherThing(): String{
        return someOtherClass.doSomeOtherThing()
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass
@Inject
constructor(

){
    fun doSomeOtherThing(): String{
        return "Look I did some other thing!"
    }
}`

I tried replacing the kapt dependences with annotationProcessor. It did remove the initial error but the app crashed whenever I tried to launch it.
This is the most basic Hilt example project
I want to inject the two text widgets in the Main Activity with the text string from separate classes but it's not working.
thanks for any help.
